# how can i implement in jQuery that my toggle-slider started with off state

Tags: jquery, html, state

i will to implement by start "off state" in my first toggle-slider (on the right side blue toggle-slider).

How can i do it with jQuery:

Here my Testsite: http://devauth.labscope.de/htmlapp/report-overview_test.html

I'm testing this in my basic.js:

```
jQuery('.toggle-dark').eq(0).toggles({on:off});
```

but this don't work.

I hope someone have i idea.

Comment: i have a start trouble but i think i can solve this with default .attr()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is a setting of the plug-in.

In your file;
http://devauth.labscope.de/htmlapp/layout/js/basic.js

Change:

```
jQuery('.toggle-dark').toggles({on:true});
```

to:

```
jQuery('.toggle-dark').toggles({on:false});
```

Comment: i tried this "jQuery('.toggle-dark').eq(0).toggles({on:off});" but this doesn't work

Comment: Correction, on: false;